# Macbook Pro running very slow and Power button needs to be held down for 7-8 secs to turn on

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, catalina, startup, performance

I have a Macbook Pro 13" Early 2015.I have been using it for about 3 years and was working completely fine. Few Months ago, my charger stopped working and I didn't use it for over 3 months. Later I searched it online and came to know that the charging pins were not coming in contact with the macbook's charging port. Later I fixed it.

After turning it on, I started booting really slow. The Power button needed to be held for 6-7 seconds. The Boot time take at least 3-4 minutes. The app takes 2-3 minutes to open up.

Things I did;

1. Formatted and Reinstalled Macos Catalina
2. RESET SMC, NVRAM and PRAM
3. Took it to technicians but they think its SMC Chip Issue. (I have no idea about it)
4. I researched it online but couldn't find anything.

I didn't have any previous backup or Time machine which I regret it now.

**I Feel like this has something to do Mac Os Catalina. Will downgrading to Mac OS Majave help?**

Please Help. Has anyone encountered this issue?